# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is not working?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to translate this Objective-C code :

```
if ([[self.appStoreCountry stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[A-Za-z]{2}" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] length])
```

So I tried to wrote this code :

```
if !self.appStoreCountry.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[A-Za-z]{2}", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range(start: 0, end: 2)).isEmpty
```

The problem is that the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString part does not seem to return a string. I have the error message from xcode : `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Bool' to type 'String'.`

I investigated a little more and tried :

```
let replaced = self.appStoreCountry.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[A-Za-z]{2}", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range(start: 0, end: 2))
```

The error message is similar but even more weird : `Cannot convert the expression's type 'String' to type 'String'.`

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug I should submit to Apple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that Foundation's types are different from Swift's types. A `String` in Swift is not an `NSString`, and a `Range` is not an `NSRange`. This does work:

```
let country = self.appStoreCountry // if self.appStoreCountry is an NSString
let country: NSString = self.appStoreCountry // if self.appStoreCountry is a Swift string

let replaced = country.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[A-Za-z]{2}", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
```

Also note the short-hand notation for `.RegularExpressionSearch`, which makes using enums in Swift a bit easier.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tend to forget that those types are different when they exist in Swift. Do you know if it is possible to use a kind of similar method using only swift ?

Comment: Well after verification, I can't use the short-hand notation for `.RegularExpressionSearch` (I have an error message).

Comment: I think you'll have to convert between `String` and `NSString`, though most of the time you'll be using `NSString` anyway, so I don't think there's that much converting that's to be done. The short-hard notation should work, what's the error?

Comment: I just don't see the point of having a String class and all the useful methods in NSString. I don't have the error anymore, maybe I made a typo... But there is no completion with this notation !

Answer (score 4):

```
extension String{
    func exclude(find:String) -> String {
        return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(find, withString: "", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
    func replaceAll(find:String, with:String) -> String {
        return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(find, withString: with, options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
}
"1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0".exclude("-")                 // "1234567890" 
"1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0".replaceAll("-", with: "+")   // "1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code:

```
var originalString="Hello World"

    var needToReplaceString = "Hello"
    var replaceString = " Hi"


    var newString = originalString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(needToReplaceString, withString: replaceString, options: nil, range: nil)

    println(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a Playground and add this code, now it's correct:

```
var str = NSString(CString: "en")

str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[A-Za-z]{2}", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))

if str == ""
{
    var a = "true"
} else {
    var b = "false"
}
```

Your problems were:

- .isEmpty is not a method of NSString
- You were using Range() and not NSRange as required by the method `.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` of NSString
- since your replace returns an empty string and not a nil object, you have to test for "" in the if statement

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tend to forget that those types are different when they exist in Swift. Do you know if it is possible to use a kind of similar method using only swift ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let maskCharSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ()-.")
let cleanedString = phoneNumber.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(maskCharSet).reduce("", combine: +)
```